# Visual Studio long project run/startup

Tags: visual-studio, performance, runtime, project

Our issue is as follows:

- solution takes a while to start up when running
- after hitting run and while monitoring the Output window, constant work done is loading project related files from .net temp dir
- this really takes a while
- this is a Web Forms app with quite a large set of UI controls/pages and about 250 DLL/component dependencies
- references are added as DLL refs and not proj refs

Given the information above, what would be some of the suggestions to speed up solution startup at run times?

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, there may not be a whole lot you can do. But be sure to disable antivirus scanning of the project, as scanning each file as it loads will slow the machine to a crawl.

There are a few other tips floating around, but I'm hoping performance will be improved via an update of some sort.

Lots of links and things to try are here:
http://www.experts-exchange.com/blogs/TheLearnedOne/B_4684-Visual-Studio-NET-2010-Performance.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, found quite a bit of useful info. But it didn't seem to solve my problem. A more specific description of the problem is that when I run the solution most of the time it's loading temp ASP.net files, and that takes a really long time. Occasionally it will crawl to a halt. Tried clearing the temp location but that didn't help. Any way to address this?